# JavaScript Draw Frame of Video to Canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a timeline using javascript and a canvas element. Typically, when the event on the timeline has an image associated to it, I use to following code to draw the image on the canvas:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image file name';
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

However, occasionally the `'image file name'` is not actually an image, it's a video. In this case, I would just like to draw a frame of the video on the canvas. It could be any frame. However, I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know (i am not web developer , i am android developer ) it is good or bed idea working with canvas for timeline but i think you should not use canvas . but i have find a video which can help you in this scenario in this video you can see that you can put image or video according your need in timeline here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrQ7IVQZtgs) .

NOTE : -

i do not own this channel or video or do not have any relation with firm .

Thank you .